# ImportError: cannot import name 'METRIC_MAPPING64' from 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics'

Tags: scikit-learn

Everything was working fine until today I install skopt and hyperopt using below commands.

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-optimize
conda install -c conda-forge hyperopt
```

Then I got below error

```
51 # from plotly_resampler import FigureResampler, FigureWidgetResampler
     52 
     53 # from kneebow.rotor import Rotor
     54 import random 
---> 55 from sklearn import manifold   # for t-SNE
     57 from sklearn import tree
     58 import joblib

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda_envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\__init__.py:5
      1 """
      2 The :mod:`sklearn.manifold` module implements data embedding techniques.
      3 """
----> 5 from ._locally_linear import locally_linear_embedding, LocallyLinearEmbedding
      6 from ._isomap import Isomap
      7 from ._mds import MDS, smacof

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda_envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\_locally_linear.py:23
     21 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     22 from ..utils.validation import FLOAT_DTYPES
---> 23 from ..neighbors import NearestNeighbors
     26 def barycenter_weights(X, Y, indices, reg=1e-3):
     27     """Compute barycenter weights of X from Y along the first axis
...
     14     ArgKminClassMode32,
     15     ArgKminClassMode64,
     16 )

ImportError: cannot import name 'METRIC_MAPPING64' from 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' (c:\ProgramData\anaconda_envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_dist_metrics.cp39-win_amd64.pyd)
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Then I also just updated sklearn using below. The error still exists. Could anyone help? Thanks

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Comment: I used this to upgrade to solve it. pip install -U scikit-learn